# Put Windows Store App images into another assembly?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I currently have an app with about 1000 different images in it. Each image has a Large and Small version. Each image further has one of four different scales, 80, 100, 140, and 180. This means that my app has a total of about 8000 images in it.

The problem is that this causes building the app to take about 5 minutes each time! This greatly disrupts my workflow, as each insignificant change requires another 5 minute wait to see changes.

I've seen it suggested that I put the images into a different library. How do I do this? I've attempted to create a `Windows Store Class Library` and put the images in there, but I'm having trouble referencing the images inside my app.

Given that the library is called `MyImageLibrary`, what is the Uri to use to access the image from Xaml? If the image is in the folder `Images`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be `ms-appx:///MyImageLibrary/Images/foo.jpg` when used in the primary app.